# Erro ao compilar o Phalcon no AWS Amazon

Tags: amazon-aws, phalcon-php

Tentei instalar o phalcon php no Amazon AWS, tive o erro abaixo

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -I. -I/home/ec2-user/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/ec2-user/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/home/ec2-user/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/home/ec2-user/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php/main -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/5.5/php/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -march=native -mtune=native -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /home/ec2-user/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.zep.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: Olá, user3511936. Vejo que você traduziu a postagem (pode inclusive remover as partes em inglês). Só não entendi direito qual seria a dúvida, tem como explicar melhor?

Comment: Não coloque a resposta dentro da pergunta, não somos um fórum, somos um Q&A, pra criar uma resposta pra sua propria pergunta clique no botão "responder". Coloque como fez para aumentar a memória na resposta, de preferencia com um passo a passo =)

Comment: Obrigado Senhores pelo esclarecimento. Meu objetivo era esse. Adicionar um erro junto a solução. Como faço para conseguir responder na minha pergunta, não aparece. Muito obrigado, desculpem quaisquer transtorno

Comment: Tem um botão azul mais abaixo dizendo `Responder à sua pergunta`, clique nele e confirme, daí poderá escrever a resposta